# PowerShell - Add Email Separator in Reply

Tags: powershell, email, outlook, html-email, office-automation

Trying to use PowerShell to reply to an email. The script works fine. But there is no email separator (the grey line) between the original email and my reply. Here is my code below.

```
Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
Add-type -assembly "System.Runtime.Interopservices"

try
{
$outlook = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Outlook.Application')
    $outlookWasAlreadyRunning = $true
}
catch
{
    try
    {
        $Outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application
        $outlookWasAlreadyRunning = $false
    }
    catch
    {
        write-host "You must exit Outlook first."
        exit
        
    }
}

$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

$inbox = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox)

$mails = $inbox.Items | Where-Object {$_.Subject -like "ABC TEST*"}

$mailsbody = $mails | Select-Object -Property Body | Format-List

$text = "Test Body"

foreach($mail in $mails) {
    $reply = $mail.reply()
    $reply.body = $reply.body.Insert(0, $text) + [Environment]::NewLine
    $reply.send()
    while(($namespace.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderOutbox)).Items.Count -ne 0) {
        Start-Sleep 1
    }
}

# Kill Process Outlook (close COM)
Get-Process "*outlook*" | Stop-Process –force
```

[image: Picture of a separator]

Answer (score 0):

The body property returns a plain text string without any formatting:

```
$reply.body = $reply.body.Insert(0, $text) + [Environment]::NewLine
```

If you need/want to preserve the existing formatting you need to use the [HTMLBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody) property instead. You can paste your new content inside the the opening `<body>` and closing `</body>` HTML tags.

Also I've noticed the following code which checks the `Subject` property of each item in the collection:

```
$mails = $inbox.Items | Where-Object {$_.Subject -like "ABC TEST*"}
```

Instead of iterating over all items in Outlook folder you need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. Read more about these methods in the articles that I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the tip about using Find instead of iterating